# ¿Por qué no me da el número anterior?

Tags: java

```
package tema2;

public class numeroenteroa {

    int x = 8;

    public int mx(){
        return x--;
    }

    numeroenteroa e; {
    e = new numeroenteroa();
    e.mx();

    System.out.println(mx());
    }
}
```

Me devuelve un 0. Quiero que me dé el número anterior,  8.

Comment: Con la e doy nombre al objeto.

Comment: si, pero para que quieres el `{`?  . además , no necesitas crear una instancia de la clase numeroenteroa si estás dentro de ella..

Comment: Tu código se ve raro o incompleto, y no lo puedo usar para reproducir tu problema (o sea que devuelva `0`). ¿Seguro que lo copiastes bien? Si no, por favor, sería bueno que lo corrigieras, si no, tu pregunta pierde su sentido, y no es muy útil para la comunidad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas realizar la operación en el método principal de la clase cuando se ejecuta la misma. `public static void main (String [] args)`

Prueba asi:

```
public class numeroenteroa {

    int x = 8;

    public int mx() {
        return x--;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        numeroenteroa myInstance = new numeroenteroa();
        System.out.println(myInstance.mx());
    }
}
```

Comment: uh te me adelantaste :D pero recuerda añadir el main

Comment: Tienes razón :)

Comment: Hola Patrick. El código que propones no puede funcionar ya que estás ejecutando un método de instancia (`mx()`) dentro de un método estático (`main()`).

Comment: Hola sstan. Eres libre de editar mi respuesta para mejorarla

Comment: @Patrick: Gracias por darme esa libertad, pero prefiero dejar esa responsabilidad en tus manos. Ya hice mi parte.

Comment: -1 porque vista la pregunta deberías explicar o poner comentarios clarificadores para que el OP entienda que esta pasando  y cuales han sido sus errores... Flaco favor le hacemos simplemente dandole el codigo que funciona... Avisame si corriges para un +1 `;)`

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Jordi. Quizá explicarm brevemente cual fue su error. Por el cual no obtuvo el resultado deseado. qué cambios hiciste y porqué.

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias. Se me había olvidado poner el public static void main.

Comment: Añadida la explicación @Dev.Joel y JordiCastilla. De nada Jonatan